# Appending Row to DataFrame in case of nested Schema in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a nested schema like this

```
root 
     |-- Vitamin: long (nullable = true)
     |-- Presents: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |-- A: Int (nullable = true)
     |    |-- B: Int (nullable = true)
     |    |-- C: Int (nullable = true)
```

Input

```
---+----+-----+
|vitamin|
+---+----+-----+
|  1     | 
+---+----+-----+
output
---+----+-----+
|vitamin|Presents
+---+----+-----+
|  1    | [1,0,1]
+---+----+-----+
```

I want to append a List of Int containing 1 and 0 to Vitamin column.
What I am doing is that

```
def append(row: Row //Here this row is the row which I want to append to) = {
val schema = StructType(Seq(StructField("A",IntegerType),StructField("B",IntegerType),StructField("C",IntegerType))

val vitaminActive: List[Int] = List(1,0,1)
val rowToAppend = new GenericRowWithSchema(vitaminActive.toArray,
        Schema)

 val values = row.toSeq ++ rowToAppend.toSeq
      val newSchema = value.schema.fields.map(field => StructField(prefix + field.name, field.dataType))

      val fields = row.schema.fields ++ newSchema

      new GenericRowWithSchema(values.toArray, StructType(fields))
```

But getting error  java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.Integer is not a valid external type for schema of java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.Integer is not a valid external type for schema of struct<A:int,B:int,C:int>

Comment: can show your expected output ?

Comment: added , basically I want to append a row to the column but dont know why I am getting this error

Comment: ok, how are you invoking append method ? and can you add full code of append method ?

Comment: Can you add the full code? what is `Schema`, `value` ?

Answer (score 0):

Check below code.

```
scala> df.show(false)
+-------+
|vitamin|
+-------+
|1      |
+-------+

scala> val vitaminActive: List[Int] = List(1,0,1)

scala> df.withColumn("Presents",struct(vitaminActive.map(lit(_)):_*).cast("struct<A:Int,B:Int,C:Int>")).show(false)
+-------+---------+
|vitamin|Presents |
+-------+---------+
|1      |[1, 0, 1]|
+-------+---------+

scala> df.withColumn("Presents",struct(vitaminActive.map(lit(_)):_*).cast("struct<A:Int,B:Int,C:Int>")).printSchema
root
 |-- vitamin: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- Presents: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- A: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- B: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- C: integer (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Thanks But not asking for code , just want to know why the above code is giving error